# Inconsistency in eigenvalues of matrices in a specific form (sparse & non-Hermitian)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Suppose one has a non-Hermitian sparse matrix defined as:

```
Clear[h]
h[a_, n_: 10] := SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}, {n, n - 1}] -> {1, a}, 
                              Band[{1, 2}, {n - 1, n}] -> {1, 0}}, n]
```

It looks harmless and simple, with nonvanishing entries only distributed on the two secondary diagonal positions, which can be seen by running codes

```
h[a] // MatrixForm
```

and one gets

[image: matrix]

If one is interested in its eigenvalues, with `a` set to various values,

```
Eigenvalues[h[#]] & /@ {a, 1, 1.}
```

Lo and behold!

```
{{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {-1.00044 + 0. I, -1.00014 + 0.000415446 I, -1.00014 - 0.000415446 I, 
  1. + 7.33851*10^-9 I, 1. - 7.33851*10^-9 I, 1. + 1.28894*10^-8 I, 
  1. - 1.28894*10^-8 I, 1. + 0. I, -0.999647 + 0.000256825 I, 
  -0.999647 - 0.000256825 I}
}
```

The first row of eigenvalues say that the eigenvalues are free of `a`, but with `a = 1.0` non-negligible imaginary parts appear, which would get larger with larger `n`s.

I don't think it a bug, because it is said that similar behavior exists also in other languages, e.g., Python & MATLAB. How to explain this, and how to correct it?

Comment: Wow, these are really huge errors. Hm. This matrix as two eigenvalues with high multiplicity. Many numerical algorithms can perform computations only stably if the eigenvalues are well separated...

Comment: This is a precision problem. See, in the following sense, the "wrong" eigensystem is quite correct: `A = h[1.];
{\[Lambda], U} = Eigensystem[A];
Max[Abs[Table[
   A.U[[i]] - \[Lambda][[i]] U[[i]], {i, 1, Length[\[Lambda]]}]]]`. Raising the working precision above `$MachinePrecision` helps; have a look at `A = h[SetPrecision[1, 100]];
{\[Lambda], U} = Chop@Eigensystem[A];`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, `SetPrecision` can deal with it. But there is another strange phenomenon that my above defined `h`, will not suffer this precision problem if transposed. Why?

Comment: Phew. Honestly, I don't know. That depends on which algorithm is used for computing the matrix. Often, a QR-factorization is performed and that induces a breaking of transposition-symmetry.

Comment: With Julia I don't get large errors (with MATLAB I do).

Comment: From the docs: "[For sparse arrays] Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors use ARPACK Arnoldi methods." I guess the first thing I'd do is to try this simple example in C with the underlying Intel library and see if I can reproduce the errors.

Comment: @halirutan Using `Eigenvalues[Normal[h[1.]]]` and `Eigenvalues[Normal[h[1.]], Method -> "Direct"]` produce _exactly_ the same errors as `Eigenvalues[h[1.]]`. Moreover `Eigenvalues[h[1.], Method -> "Arnoldi"]` says it does not what to try to compute all eigenvalues. So I am pretty sure that Arnoldi method is not used here.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, because I tried all the methods. However, there are only two mentions of EigentValues in the *internal implementation details doc* and the other one is for exact values. I really wonder what the "Direct" method really is.

Comment: @halirutan I guess this is one of the standard LAPACK routines; maybe `dggev`/`sggev` as the symbol ``LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GGEV`​`` suggests. But I cannot be sure of course.

Comment: With respect to "correcting": are you aware that you can use a similarity transformation to symmetrize your tridiagonals? Also, it has been known for quite a while that a number of unsymmetric tridiagonals are troublesome for eigensystem methods.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the information. Could you please provide any references with detailed contents on this?

Comment: I'll write more when I am at a computer again, but Wilkinson's *The Algebraic Eigenvalue Problem* talks about that similarity transformation.

Comment: Sorry for the very late follow-up, but: the transformation of Wilkinson I was talking about only works if all of the off-diagonal elements are nonzero. In any event: if you look at the result of `Last[JordanDecomposition[h[a, 10]]]`, you will notice that it has *two* Jordan blocks, which explains a lot on why `Eigenvalues[]` has trouble with it.

Answer (score 1):

It naively looks like a precision problem, but increasing the precision does not immediately help. For example, with OP's definitions, I find on my computer following results:

```
Eigenvalues[h[1]]
Eigenvalues[h[1.`5]]
Eigenvalues[h[1.`10]]
Eigenvalues[h[1.`100]]
```

> {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
>
> {-1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000 + 3.2888*10^-10 I, -1.0000 - 
>     3.2888*10^-10 I, 1.0000 + 1.6608*10^-9 I, 1.0000 - 1.6608*10^-9 I, 
>    1.0000 + 3.6260*10^-10 I, 1.0000 - 3.6260*10^-10 I, -1.0000, -1.0000}
>
> {-1.000000000, 1.000000000 + 1.941032805*10^-11 I, 
>    1.000000000 - 1.941032805*10^-11 I, 1.000000000, -1.000000000 + 
>     6.539486873*10^-20 I, -1.000000000 - 
>     6.539486873*10^-20 I, -1.000000000, 
>    1.000000000 + 8.442441251*10^-20 I, 
>    1.000000000 - 8.442441251*10^-20 I, -1.000000000}
>
> {-1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110954162\
>   5915143645283700322398250961229805, \
>   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   00000000000000000000000000000000, \
>   -1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
>     2.976853631677875691628349618766633756396719842482978185187919770933\
>   308169805544158257069331975894975*10^-58 I, \
>   -1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000 - 
>     2.976853631677875691628349618766633756396719842482978185187919770933\
>   308169805544158257069331975894975*10^-58 I, 
>    1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
>     3.558020626382386620531022727918765817478289860513062693986158315078\
>   213370359938021098572273950853424*10^-58 I, 
>    1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000 - 
>     3.558020626382386620531022727918765817478289860513062693986158315078\
>   213370359938021098572273950853424*10^-58 I, 
>    1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000 + 
>     3.328624877745430935851100967194752883689414382046741134022348191945\
>   432724468803967697080267882337017*10^-58 I, 
>    1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000 - 
>     3.328624877745430935851100967194752883689414382046741134022348191945\
>   432724468803967697080267882337017*10^-58 I, \
>   -1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
>   000000000000000000000000000000000, \
>   -0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998890458374\
>   0848563547162996776017490387701952}

Of course, we can use `Chop` or `N` at the end to get rid of the tails, but that does not solve the problem of getting these results out of `Eigenvalues` command.

One *dirty* way to solve this is to introduce an auxiliary symbolic variable to the process to avoid possible inner cancellations, and then take that variable to zero. For the same examples above, if we now run

```
Eigenvalues[h[1] + ConstantArray[\[Epsilon], {10, 10}]] /. \[Epsilon] -> 0
Eigenvalues[h[1.`5] + ConstantArray[\[Epsilon], {10, 10}]] /. \[Epsilon] -> 0
Eigenvalues[h[1.`10] + ConstantArray[\[Epsilon], {10, 10}]] /. \[Epsilon] -> 0
Eigenvalues[h[1.`100] + ConstantArray[\[Epsilon], {10, 10}]] /. \[Epsilon] -> 0
```

one gets

> {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
>
> {-1.00, -1.00, -1.00, -1.00, -1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}
>
> {-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}
>
> {-1.000000000000000000, -1.000000000000000000, -1.000000000000000000, \
>   -1.000000000000000000, -1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, \
>   1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, 1.000000000000000000, \
>   1.000000000000000000}

which is way better than the previous ones.

I am sure this method would fail under certain scenarios, e.g. adding a symbolic number may prevent finding all roots of characteristic polynomial. Still, this may be a quick work-around.

Comment: The matrix is *[defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix)*, so `Eigenvalues[]` will surely have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to just construct the characteristic polynomial and find the zeros yourself:

```
Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[h[a], x] == 0, x]
Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[h[1.], x] == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 
>      1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 1}}
>
> {{x -> -1.}, {x -> -1.}, {x -> -1.}, {x -> -1.}, {x -> -1.}, {x -> 1.}, {x -> 
>      1.}, {x -> 1.}, {x -> 1.}, {x -> 1.}}